# How to append/copy an STL container object to another object when its value is not copy constructible e.g. std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, compiler-errors, rvalue

I want to **move** an `std::map` container object to another. In simplest form:

```
#include<map>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  map<void*, vector<thread>> m1, m2; 
  // m1 is updated 

  m1.insert(m2.begin(), m2.end());  // <--- problem here
  m2.clear();  // not required anymore
}
```

However it gives a page of [error](http://ideone.com/l2eMpy):

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)’
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, you cannot copy the threads. The only suggestion I have is a `map<void*, vector<shared_ptr<thread>>>` (or a `map<void*, shared_ptr<vector<thread>>>`, whichever seems more appropriate).

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really make sense -- what does it mean to copy a thread? Do you want to move it instead?

Comment: @Cameron, yes actually it's move. After that I would run `m2.clear()`.

Comment: @iammilind: Even better, in that case you can simply move the whole map at once: `m1 = std::move(m2);` (After which `m2` will be in a valid, but unspecified, state -- if you want to repurpose it for another use, simply clear it first.)

Comment: @Cameron, That's good. But in the code it is over simplified (now updated). Actually `m1` is already having some values and I want to move/append `m2` values into it.

Comment: @iammilind: Ah, then go with one of the `std::make_move_iterator` answers (followed by the `m2.clear()` to get rid of the empty object husks), which will move the items into `m1` appropriately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::thread` is not copy-constructible, you'll have to use an iterator that allows moves:

```
m1.insert(std::make_move_iterator(m2.begin()),
          std::make_move_iterator(m2.end());
```

`std::make_move_iterator` returns a specialized iterator class `std::move_iterator` whose access members (`operator*()` and `operator->()`) return references to rvalues unlike the built in iterators that return lvalues. `map::insert()` delegates its operation to `map::emplace()` where it forwards the argument into the element type.

Your threads' copy-constructors were being called because the objects returned from the built-in iterators were being forwarded as *lvalues* and thus copied.

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, there is a little-known version of `std::move` in `<algorithm>` that follows a similar pattern to `std::copy`.

So you can write this:

```
move(begin(m2), end(m2), inserter(m1, begin(m1)));
m2.clear();
```

[reference here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move)

Answer (score 3):

Move them, using move iterators:

```
m1.insert(make_move_iterator(begin(m2)), make_move_iterator(end(m2)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to insert a range of elements which are only movable. You should be able to `std::move()` the individual elements, though:

```
for (auto& element: m2) {
    m1.emplace(element.first, std::move(element.second));
}
```

Comment: On the contrary, there's `std::make_move_iterator`. But it's not semantically the same as a copy, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution: move it.

However, while `std::move()` can move a single value, it can't move a range of values. You'll need to write a loop:

```
for (auto&& pair : m1) m2[pair.first] = std::move(pair.second)
```